# SSH Commands That Run In a Loop In C#

Tags: c#, ssh

I have +30 images file on remote server(windows). I do various ssh operations(scp,del,dir) this files. There isn't a problem when run step by step but i'm getting errors when run with loops.

**My code for files delete:**

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.Verb = "runas";

foreach (var file in sourceFileList)
{
     //file as like 1234.png
     startInfo.Arguments = $@"/C ssh {sourceUserName}@{sourceIp} del {sourcePath}\{file}";
     process.StartInfo = startInfo;
     process.Start();
     process.WaitForExit();
     process.Close();
}
```

When I run this code, some files are deleted, some files are not. But when I run it step by step(debug mode) I see that it deletes all the files.

**Error Details:**

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xx.xx.xx.xx is address
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xx.xx.xx.xx is address
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port xx.
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\xuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\xuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/xuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\xuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\xuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
```

Comment: So how do you call this code?

Comment: I'm running it via a simple console application. @RenéVogt

Comment: Have you tried putting the declaration of the `process` variable inside the loop?

Comment: @mennowo Yes but it didn't work.

Comment: My first step would be to a delay in the loop, cause that would seem to be the main difference between a single and a batch operation. The remote server may still be processing some IO operation. Eg. add `Thread.Sleep(250);` or `await Task.Delay(250);` depending on the context of your code.

Comment: I try it but im got error "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset"